# Parent ul should change when I hover child il

Tags: html, css, hover, parent-child

I am creating a dropdown menu for a Wordpress template and I want the main menuitem to have the same color the subitems have when they are hovered. I found many similar questions here on stack overflow and tried their solutions but they don't seem to work in my case.

I think the solution must be:

```
parent:hover child { ... }
```

and it works for example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/esBrF/).

I tried to do the same with [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/BpGu9/) (please see last CSS selector) but it doesn't work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your CSS from:

```
#menu ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #006699;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

To

```
#menu ul li:hover a {
    background-color: #006699;
}
#menu ul li a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Updated example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gNU63/).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the effect you'd like by replacing the last CSS declaration in your fiddle with this:

```
.menu ul li:hover > a {
    background-color: #006699;
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

Comment: I didn't notice it at first, but both `.menu` and `#menu` exist.